# What is the best way to configure an iDRAC/dell server in a public data center such that the idrac doesn't have to be exposed public facing

Tags: networking, security, openvpn, drac

I have a server right now in a data center behind an OpenVPN using the client on the box to connect to the vpn server.  I'm going to install the iDRAC and want to know how to best configure the network/server setup so that the iDRAC can also be protected by a VPN tunnel only (not public facing).

Comment: Assign it an RFC 1918 ip address?

Comment: In my company i have a dedicated vlan for iDrac admin Network. From there i can easily route (or not) and filter (FW) it where i want. Not sure to understand where the real problem is...